# Does the bluetooth socket in any way influence the WiFi socket?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth logic that tries to connect to BT hardware nonstop. One `socket.connect()` takes about 3 seconds and once it returns unsuccessful, a new one is started.

While it is trying to connect on many devices no WiFi connection can be established. Once the BT connection stands, WiFi works as usual. It doesnt matter what app wants wifi, it just wont get it for as long as my app is machine-gunning the socket.connects() (just one at a time, but nearly zero delay between them)

I believe that somewhere i read something about a shared "socket" or something in the hardware. I would like to know if that is true.

Can i attempt to connect a bt socket (in a nonstop fashion) AND have WiFi operating at the same time ?

**Edit, regarding battery life:**

24h running this routine is barely noticeable where as simply having wifi activited for 24h really drains the battery... so would having a 24h bt connection, but if its wanted then thats what it costs. It's up to the user.

Comment: battery life is not a point of concern in this matter. The behaviour is a requirement, no need to downvote for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same behavior. I have yet to determine why this happens, but failed calls to BluetoothSocket.connect() will cause any active connections over the wifi radio to timeout.

This behavior is reproducible on an S5, S4 and S3. Probably other devices as well.

My 'fix' was to introduce a mutex to synchronize my wifi radio usage as well as bluetooth socket connection. I admit this is pretty crude, but it is a functional workaround.

Comment: thx for finally confirming this. I can add note 1 and note 2 plus S2 to the list of samsung devices. Can you please explain the mutex a bit ?

Comment: Instantiate an object that will be used to control access to syncronized(Object) {} code blocks. Share that object between the bluetooth and tcp code.

Comment: only works within the same app unfortunately. But the wifi is blocked for the entire device and i cant make other apps understand the mutex

Comment: Yep, it's not an ideal workaround. Although if you wanted to use lockfiles or something, I guess it could be doable. Look at the nio FileLock class.

Answer (score 0):

Up voted to get you back to 0 :)

I'm seeing the same sort of behavior in my app... constantly trying to connect to a bluetooth device which is unavailable results in wifi failing.

Really annoying, I'm going to reduce the poll frequency for attempting BT connection and hope that lets wifi traffic trickle through at least.

Comment: Definitely locks up WiFi completely while going through the process of trying to connect to the Bluetooth device on my Samsung Galaxy S4.

I have a background process which is continually pushing data to a server via WiFi... it dies completely when my other thread is repeatedly trying to connect to the Bluetooth device (I need to handle it loosing connection and auto-reconnecting). I've reduced poll frequency for re-connect attempts to 10 seconds which does give my other process a bit of room to push data.

Comment: I might do something similar to the way gMail handles disconnected internet... an increasing poll frequency for each failed attempt, with a button to force a re-connect attempt.

Answer (score 0):

BluetoothSocket is only design to be similar to WiFi. In fact there are completely different.

My application uses BT sockets (up to 2 BT sockets per a device) to communicate between devices, as well as WiFi for advertising.

I've noticed that some manufacturers do not implement Bluetooth correctly. Samsung Galaxy devices always work nice and smoothly, however there are sometimes connection issues with Motorola and HTC.

Comment: can you have an active wifi connection while you run a BluetoothSocket.connect() (that is not connecting) or not ?

Comment: No, Wifi connection comes a bit later